# How to do load/library

Tags: dll, rebol, rebol3

In the past, using REBOL/Command, this worked fine.  Now, I'm trying to `load/library` a `.dll` that I compiled and there is no `/library` refinement for `load` any longer.  What is the equivalent in Rebol 3?  Do I have to make an `'extension` and `import` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Rebol 3 does not currently contain a Rebol 2-like DLL interface, which was limited and did not offer many useful options to wrap libraries, and e.g. callbacks were very limited too. Rebol 3 solved the situation by introducing an extension mechanism, which involves a little bit of a C code.

There was also some initiative to bring in improved Rebol 2-like DLL interface in form of a Rebol 3 extension, but the project did not work out yet, although after the ReCode conference, someone was claiming, it will come.

What you could also use is Red/System: it is a Rebol-like language, but very close to C level, so rather easy to wrap things around. Kaj De Vos created some examples, which show how to [write an Rebol 3 extension as Red/System DLL](http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-REBOL-3/dir?ci=tip&name=examples).

Comment: Are there any good guide/tutorials for using Red/System DLL Extensions? The examples on their own are not as clear as they could be...

Answer (score 2):

Since this was answered, some versions of Rebol3 eg. Atronix, have the foreign function library compiled in so that you can

```
make library! %some.dll
```

See https://github.com/zsx/r3/blob/atronix/make/tests/ms-drives.r for an example on windows, and https://github.com/zsx/c2r3/blob/master/demos/gtk-demos/gtk-demo.reb for a comprehensive linux example.